# Passing List<string> from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python

I can send a list as one big string argument, and then split it in Python, but the argument has a maximum of 32000 characters. Is there a better way?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "C:\\Python33\\python.exe";

        List<string> myAL = new List<string>();
        myAL.Add("Hello");
        myAL.Add("World");
        myAL.Add("!");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            myAL.Add("string" + i);
        }

        string ukupno = myAL[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < myAL.Count; i++)
        {
              if(i!=0)
             ukupno += ',' +  myAL[i];
        }
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "C:\\Users\\My\\Desktop\\module1.py", ukupno, myAL.Count);

                using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {                 
                }

    }
```

Comment: Send the data to the Python script on standard input rather than as a command line argument.

Comment: It is not much better. It would be good whole list to send.

Comment: How is it "not much better" to be able to send an unlimited amount of data when your complaint is the limit on the amount of data?